# How to set JPA @Version marked field to explicit value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Having the entity class:

```
@Entity
class Foo {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Version
    java.time.Instant ts;
}
```

I need to persist it with the explicit value of `ts` field in DB. However if I set the value of ts explicitly, it's overwritten by the JPA automatically.

I've seen the solution for the update, however it's not working for me, as I need it on insert already:
[Is it possible to turn off hibernate version increment for particular update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972564/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-hibernate-version-increment-for-particular-update/33976362#33976362)

I can't remove the `@Version` as it's in the parent class of my entity.

Moreover, I can't disable the behaviour in general. Would need it for the specific use-case only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic-version-number):

> *Your application is forbidden from altering the version number set by Hibernate.* To artificially increase the version number, see the documentation for properties `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` or `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` check in the Hibernate Entity Manager reference documentation.
>
> If the version number is generated by the database, such as a trigger, use the annotation `@org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)` on the version attribute.